# Error in SQL syntax after sending post request to web page form in python

Tags: python, json, post, request, http-method

I need to post some json data here: https://online.superpoistenie.sk/pzp/kalkulacka/

the webpage will proceed data and show results 
Basicly you insert some info and the webpage will generate all possible prices from different brands for your insurance specificly car.

Basicly i want to

1. post json data to page
2. get back answer from page in json
3. best result will be if i will get name of company name of the offer and price

I am only interested in cars.

I tried to do this in node.js with axios didnt got far and i was new to node.js now i am using python and request lib and i am having some nice answer i just cant finish it.

Here is my code:

```
import requests, json, urllib3, bs4, pprint  

url = "https://online.superpoistenie.sk/pzp/kalkulacka/" 

json_head = "/predvolba.json"

json_file = "C:/Users/GC/Desktop/web crawler poistovne/Json_Storage" 

payload = json_file + json_head

with open(payload, 'r') as f:              
    data = f.read()
    json_data = json.loads(data)

pprint.pprint(json_data)                             


try:

    r = requests.post(url, data=json_data, headers="")
    pprint.pprint(r.status_code)                            

except EnvironmentError as er:
    print('Decoding json failed')
    print(er)

r = requests.get(url)
print(r)                               #will output code 200

r = requests.post(url, json_data)                      
print(r)                               #will output code 200                                          
print(r.content)
```

the output is html file with error codes in it meaning i screwed up something in json but i dont know what. i want it to be html code with the redirected page after i send form and i want to filter the html code to parts where the name of company are and prices.

Thanks so much for any answer!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. As currently formulated, it's quite difficult to answer your question. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. We will need at least the json contents and the exact response text to be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

this is the json i am seding to the site

[
    {
        "comp838":0
    },
    {
        "comp839":null
    },
    {
        "typ_vozidla":"1"
    },
    {
        "len_pzp_check":true
    },
    {
        "comp773":5
    },
    {
        "comp771":1
    },
    {
        "comp770":"motorka"
    },
    {
        "comp769":"do+3%2C5+t"
    },
    {
        "comp143":"BMW"
    },
    {
        "comp144":"rad%2F%F8ada+2+Cabriolet"
    },
    {
        "comp763": "BMW"
    },
    {
        "comp772":"-vyberte-zo-zoznamu-"
    },
    {
        "comp167":"Benz%EDn"
    },
    {
        "comp678":"%28F23%29+%282014-%29+Benz%EDn&prevedenie=2-dv.%2C+4-m.%2C+kabriolet%2C+osob."
    },
    {
        "comp600":"2-dv.%2C+4-m.%2C+kabrilet%2C+osob."
    },
    {
        "comp677":"3.0+%282998+ccm%2C+250+kW%2C+turbo+29"
    },
    {
        "comp147":"250"
    },
    {
        "comp148":"2998"
    }, 
    {
        "comp149":"2000"
    },
    {
        "comp157":"1"
    },
    {
        "comp779":"Adam"
    },
    {
        "comp780":"Tilingerov"
    },
    {
        "comp781":"Adam"
    },
    {
        "comp782":"Tilingerov"
    },
    {
        "comp158":"1982"
    },
    {
        "comp150":"90028"
    },
    {
        "comp151":"90028--Z%E1lesie%ESC%%EBA"
    },
    {
        "comp212":"0947588699"
    },
    {
        "comp211":"learningpotential2%40gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "comp205":"1"
    },
    {
        "comp286":"1"
    },
    {
        "comp287":"1"
    },
    {
        "comp810":"1"
    },
    {
        "comp288":"0"
    },
    {
        "comp591":"0"
    },
    {
        "comp401":"Nie"
    },
    {
        "comp806": "1"
    },
    {
        "typ_vozidla":1
    },
    {
        "len_pzp_check":true
    },
    {
        "tel_pov":22
    },
    {
        "odoslany_kasko":3
    },
    {
        "scenar":1
    },
    {
        "zmena":false
    }
]

Comment: i am getting this output:                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                 
 200
'https://online.superpoistenie.sk/pzp/kalkulacka/index.php'                                                           
                                                                                                                                thats all